# Handling Facebook/Google login with ngCordovaOauth in Ionic + Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication, ngcordova

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication with angularfire signInWithCredential method for my Ionic app. As I'm using Firebase 3.x SDK, the methods signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup are not yet supported on mobile devices. Thus I'm using the plugin ngCordovaOauth.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users");
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);
$cordovaOauth.facebook("//removed_client_id", [ "public_profile", "email"]).then(function(result) {
  var credentials = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.access_token);
  $scope.authObj.$signInWithCredential(credentials).then(function(authData) {
    var existUser = $scope.users.$getRecord(authData.uid);
    if(existUser == null){
      $scope.user = {
        uid: authData.uid,
        displayName: authData.displayName,
        avatar: authData.photoURL,
        email: authData.email,
        contact: "0000000000",
        provider: "facebook"
      }
      firebase.database().ref("users/" + authData.uid).set($scope.user);
    }
    $rootScope.result = authData;
    $state.go("menu.home");
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("ERROR: " + error);
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + error);
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is I have no idea what the structure of 'authdata' is as I couldn't find any documentation for the same. With sigInWithPopup, firebase returns 'result' object; contents of which can be accessed like 'result.user.uid', 'result.user.displayName' or 'result.user.email'. How can I achieve the same here as I'm trying to store the user profile when he logs in for the first time? Any help? I'm testing on android device. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

signInWithCredential returns a promise that resolves with a firebase.User same as signInWithEmailAndPassword and all other sign in apis.
Check the docs for more info on firebase.User:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User